Evaluating and keeping track of algorithm performance over time
I am curious how industry keeps track of performance of their implementation. For example, consider we keep capturing robot sensor data over time / over many months as we perform multiple robot work sessions per day and we also keep optimizing our system / algorithm. Now how you maintain all this data and evaluate performance of the updated system / algorithm over say randomly selected historical data?
One may need:

Organize the data
Run latest or select code commit of the system / algorithm against some input or randomly selected data.
Store the performance metric of the run in the database.
Check if there are considerable degradation in the performance.
Visualize the performance with different custom visualizations / graphs / plots.
Given old data IDs and commit IDs, fetch corresponding run results and provide analysis / visualization.

Is there any framework for this or you guys do it all from scratch?
